# Cannot get rid of error thrown by Crashlytics on a complex project

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I have been trying for over a week to integrate Crashlytics in one of my project. I have tried the following things..

- If I tried to implement in a newly created project containing none of the dependencies and their usage too, which I will show you below, Crashlytics gets configured automatically after following the official docs by Firebase.
- If I tried to implement it in a project containing the following dependencies and their usage too in the project, it throws 3 kinds of errors.

  1. `Must initialize Fabric before using singleton.`
     When I initialize Fabric in one of my Application class, then after compiling, it shows following error..
  2. `Fabric Api key is missing from manifest, Please add it in manifest` or something like that.
     When I resolved it too by copying api key from my console in fabric.io and pasting it in manifest appropriately,
     then it showed following error after compiling.
  3. `The Crashlytics build ID is missing.` 
     And this is the error which never ever goes even If I tried various solutions related to that. It just never goes.

But the thing to note is that all this extra things are not required when I added Crashlytics to a simple project **NOT** containing following dependencies and their usage in project.

Here are those dependencies

```
implementation project(':library')
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.4.0'

implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.13.0'


implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'

/* dagger dependency for DI*/
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.23.2"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.23.2"
compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'

/*Retrofit lib*/
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.0'

/*RxJava lib*/
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9"
implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'

/* LiveData lib*/
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.1.0'
annotationProcessor 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.1.0'

/* Crashlytics */
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'

/* Necessary library for handling permission callbacks easily */
implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:3.0.0'

/* Better logging */
implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'
```

And also this is a project built by me and my mate and I don't know why he has added another project inside this one in the form of a module named "library" thats why you can see `implementation project(':library')`
line at the beginning. But I have tried removing it too and copying this project's files inside the project only instead of adding it as separate module, but that didn't change anything in the error which is occurring.

If any of you guys know a workaround or any solution to this strange behavior of Crashlytics in two different scenarios, do reply .

**EDIT:**
Here is the manifest file without key as requested

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="fibamlscan.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_today"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup,GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        tools:targetApi="m">
        <activity android:name=".s2s_transfer.S2STransferScanner" />
        <activity android:name=".s2s_transfer.S2STransferActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".stock_transfer_received.StockTransferReceivedActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".damaged_goods.DamagedGoodsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".dispatch.CreateNewDispatchActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".dispatch.DispatchOrder"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_dispatch_order"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".menu.MenuActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_menu"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".ui.login.LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".grn.PreviewActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".grn.GrnOrder"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_grn"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".dispatch.PreviewActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".metro.dispatch.PreviewActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".goodsreturn.CreateNewDispatchActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".goodsreturn.PreviewActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".goodsreturn.DispatchOrder" />
        <activity android:name=".metro.dispatch.DispatchOrder" />
        <activity android:name=".warehouseAudit.PreviewActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".audit.PreviewActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".damaged_goods.DamagedGoodsScanner" />
        <activity android:name=".warehouseAudit.WarehouseSelectionActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.ml.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="barcode" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**EDIT:**

This is the app level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "co.behtarinternal.app"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode rootProject.ext.versionCode
        versionName "${rootProject.ext.versionName}"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
//            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation project(':library')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.4.0'

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.13.0'


    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'

    /* dagger dependency for DI*/
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.23.2"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.23.2"
    compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'

    /*Retrofit lib*/
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.0'

    /*RxJava lib*/
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9"
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'

    /* LiveData lib*/
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.1.0'

    /* Crashlytics */
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'

    /* Necessary library for handling permission callbacks easily */
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:3.0.0'

    /* Better logging */
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: please post your manifest file without key

Comment: show the top of your gradle you are probably missing the `apply plugin: 'io.fabric` or something in your gradle

Comment: Okay will upload the gradle code too

Comment: Is this a react native app?

Comment: Nope. It is not. It is build in Android Studio for Android